# Access IIf statement to extract values

Tags: ms-access, iif

I have Excel export within Access 2007. The only thing I am not entirely sure about is I have value that appears as an age, for example "1-3", this obviously becomes higher dependent on customer selection.

I want two IIf statements: one to select the data before the "-" and one for after "-", can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean you have a column containing "1-3" and you want to match that with the inputs "1", "2" or "3" ? If so a `fldFrom | fldTo` would be better

Comment: Hi, Alex Yes its containing "1-3 and in the export i want that to come in two separte number the number 1 in one coloum and the number 3 in another coloum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IIf(IsNull([strAge]),"",Left([strAge],InStr(1,[strAge],"-")-1)) 

IIf(IsNull([strAge]),"",Mid([strAge],InStr(1,[strAge],"-")+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

```
select
  T.agerange, 
  iif(agerange is null, "", left(agerange,instr(agerange,"-")-1)), 
  iif(agerange is null, "", mid(agerange,instr(agerange,"-")+1))
from T;
```

however a 2 column design would be far superior.

Comment: Whats above should return `1-3, 1, 3`?

Comment: I've updated to allow for nulls, this will work for xxx-xxx formats, if it does not you need to provide more details as to why

Comment: IIf(IsNull([strAge]),"",Left([strAge],InStr(1,[strAge],"-")-1))

Comment: IIf(IsNull([strAge]),"",Mid([strAge],InStr(1,[strAge],"-")+1))

Comment: I would amend the second iif from using a mid to the following "right(agerange,InStrRev(agerange,"-")-1" this will ensure it still works if your age is more than a single digit. +1 still though as this is a great answer. : )